# Database for create model in xts

Tags: r, matrix, xts

I have a question concerning the package " XTS ". What is the optimal databases format for cooperation with "XTS"? More precisely - what is the recommended database format used for cooperation eg package "performance analytics". Using one large matrix linking the data of companies would be appropriate ? Or perhaps more useful to apply a single matrix of data? Can you give me examples of the use of a particular database?

Ultimately, I'm interested in construction investment model. Do you have any advice on what packages other packages besides the XTS and "performance analytics" I will need to build such a model ? What else to consider?

Thanks for any help,

Comment: This might be better asked on the Programmers site (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @KarlWilbur this is off-topic at Programmers, touching on both "resource request" and "product support." Please read: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/22815)**.

Comment: Thanks, I was just thinking of "IDE vs. whiteboard". Seems more like a "whiteboard" question.